# Why do my quad copter motors slowly decrease RPM with full throttle?

Tags: quadcopter

The flight controller is setup using LibrePilot, no propellers are fitted, when I put the throttle of the transmitter to full the motors go to full RPM and then slowly decrease to zero RPM with no change in the position of the throttle. This repeats over time.

Check this video for visual symptoms: [Quad motors slowly decrease RPM over time with full throttle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-MfsQCzoV8).

This also happens when all the props are fitted.

Comment: Just a thought, are the ESC's getting too hot? Are they sufficiently rated for the motors? I see that someone else had the same, or similar problem [motors increase / decrease speed on their own](https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?2612959-motors-increase-decrease-speed-on-their-own), but there was no resolution of *that* issue. Are your symptoms the same? Are all of the motors behaving the same, or is it just diagonally opposites? Is the quadcopter on a level surface? Have the ESCs been calibrated first? Could you edit and update your question just to clarify these points?

Comment: Have you put a volt meter across the motor to see if the voltage on the motor is dropping?  Also check the battery voltage.

Comment: Could you describe your power electronics from the battery specs to the ESC, looks like an powering issue to me. Can you test the same with a power supply instead of battery ?

Comment: There is no way to diagnose this with only a video.  It should be closed under the assumption the the OP found the issue and did no feel it was beneficial to share it.